# Pl SQL count rows from 100 views without union all

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to count the number of rows each view has in an oracle database.

There are over 100 views.

I want it to display the view name and the number of rows.

I tried

```
SELECT VIEW_NAME, COUNT(*) FROM ALL_VIEWS
```

But this doesn't work.

I tried a similar query using a group by of `view_name and max(rownum)` but this too didn't work.

The SQL I'm writing is generating the count of `view_names or max(rownum)`'s assigned to `view_names`. I need the count of rows for each individual `view_name`.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Thanks,

Rob

Comment: I believe you're on a right track. You will have to create a query to get all your view names, iterate over this list and query for count(*) for each of them separately. There is no way I can think of to do it in a single query though. Create a so called stored procedure which will run the queries and create the result you want. Check this site http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/ or similar. The options differ across database vendors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you have the views:

```
create or replace view viewTwoRows as select level as l from dual connect by level <= 2;
create or replace view viewTenRows as select level as l from dual connect by level <= 10;
```

You can query each view in a single statement with:

```
select view_name,
       to_number(extractvalue( xmltype(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||VIEW_NAME)) ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) 
from all_views;

VIEW_NAME                             NUM
------------------------------ ----------
VIEWTENROWS                            10
VIEWTWOROWS                             2
```

In a different way, you can loop through the views and query them; for example:

```
declare
    c number;
begin
    for i in (
                select view_name, 'select count(*) as c from ' || view_name as statement
                from all_views
             ) loop
        execute immediate i.statement into c;
        dbms_output.put_line('View ' || i.view_name || ': ' || c);
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. A colleague suggested the exact same way. Is it possible to go down the LOOP route to achieve the same result? I'd be interested to know as I felt I was close to getting the results with LOOP. Thanks, Rob.

Comment: Just added an example with a loop